# multiple host share one domain name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have a few hosts IP e.g. 192.168.101.101 till 192.168.101.103, each has different web application. Need combine all under one domain name e.g. 202.12.30.1
Created a webpage to link to all three hosts and individual host IP cannot display to client.

Code create 3 link:
    Response.Redirect("http://192.168.101.101/product")
    Response.Redirect("http://192.168.101.102/account")
    Response.Redirect("http://192.168.101.103/member")

web.config (I have problem to put in < symbol, all < is omitted):

```
rewrite>
outboundRules>
rule name="test1">
match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern=".*192.168.101.101/(.*)" />
action type="Rewrite" value="http://202.12.30.1/{R:1}" />
/rule>

rule name="test2">
match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern=".*192.168.101.102/(.*)" />
action type="Rewrite" value="http://202.12.30.1/{R:1}" />
/rule>

rule name="test3">
match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern=".*192.168.101.103/(.*)" />
action type="Rewrite" value="http://202.12.30.1/{R:1}" />
/rule>
/outboundRules>
/rewrite>
```

E.g. click link 1 transfer to http://192.168.101.101/product and should display http://202.12.30.1/product to client.

click link 2 transfer to http://192.168.101.102/account and should display http://202.12.30.1/account to client.

Url display as setting but has http error 404.0 - page not found. How to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use an [API gateway](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html). This is a microservice which redirects incoming requests to a given endpoint, waits for the answer of the endpoint and sends the answer back to the client.

Technically, you must implement a lightweight web-service, e.g. with Katana / OWIN + Topshelf. This web-service listens to requests on the different routes and has the following endpoints:

```
202.12.30.1/product
202.12.30.1/account
202.12.30.1/member
```

Then the service has an intern routing table which redirects the request to the matching service:

```
202.12.30.1/product -> 192.168.101.101/product
202.12.30.1/account -> 192.168.101.102/account
202.12.30.1/member  -> 192.168.101.103/member
```

If you have further questions, please write below this post. Hope this helps you!

Comment: hi seb, thanks you your reply. i'm still new in IIS. not sure how to start with 'API gateway', isn't by coding? katana found a few link but i can't start programming 'coz can't find OWIN class ([1], [2], [3]). please teach me start from basic....., thanks you.

[1]: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api
[2]: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/overview-of-owin-and-katana.htm
[3]: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Katana/AspNetRoutes/Startup.cs